# Counterintuitive effect between event horizons of a 'binary black hole system'

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, event-horizon

I recently posted a question on my 'mobile phone profile' where I cannot post images and videos so I am trying to use this profile to solve my incomprehension of a gravitational-tidal effect that happens when two black holes approach their perihelia. So as gravity in a point of a common astronomic object weaken due to a tidal effect of an orbiting object in the case of a BH it happens simply the opposite. So I am now, trying to visualize dark energy as a source that increases the amount of an unknown fluid in every point of the universe and a gravitation body like a BH as a drain or a sink of that 'fluid' and that this source provides to the sink a same amount of fluid per time. Is it now possible think that when the two BHs approach each other they drastically increase the drain potential of their 'fluid sink' bodies where they are facing each other and the 'space fluid' gets more 'volume to sink into' so it becomes faster in every chosen point near the two facing parts of the two BH event horizons than it were before which means that it increases velocity also in front of the former event horizons points and as a consequence the event horizons extend away from the BHs centers....Please keep in mind this is only my speculation as I try to clear the uncomprehensive, counterintuitive gravitational-tidal effect at the binary BH system event horizons...so please find gaps in this approach to clear up with this 'tricky' problem I tried to present...(somebody can find this question wrong and not hesitate to downvote but I just want to see other approaches and ideas...Thank You very much for any assistance.)

Comment: When two black holes approach each other, their horizons extend away from their centers and toward each other. Here is a mathematically correct video showing this effect just before two black holes merge into one: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ&feature=youtu.be